# Which are the classes used for User Authentication in alfresco.4.2.c in the case of External SSO?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am trying to implement External SSO in alfresco share. I am using alfresco.4.2.c.
I want to enable debug mode for the classes which are using for Authentication in the case of External SSO. 
So please let me know the class names which are using in External SSO.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which SSO you are integrating say OpenAM, CAS etc

SlingshotUserFactory class is used for default authentication in Alfresco Share
You can override its entry as below in share-config-custom.xml

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="WebFramework">
        <web-framework>
            <!-- SpringSurf Autowire Runtime Settings -->
            <!-- Developers can set mode to 'development' to disable; SpringSurf caches, 
                FreeMarker template caching and Rhino JavaScript compilation. -->
            <defaults>
                <page-type>
                    <id>login</id>
                    <page-instance-id>slingshot-login</page-instance-id>
                </page-type>
                <user-factory>webframework.factory.user.custom.slingshot
                </user-factory>
            </defaults>
        </web-framework>
    </config>
```

Add below entry in custom-slingshot-application-context.xml

```
<bean id="webframework.factory.user.custom.slingshot" class="com.test.web.site.ExtSlingshotUserFactory"
        parent="webframework.factory.user.slingshot">
</bean>
```

now on login it will call your class for authentication

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
But i am not using OpenAM, CAS etc. I am trying to access Alfresco from another application by clicking on the URL appended with the ticket. Created a special sso filter that is able to pass the ticket to the Alfresco Repository. Configured share-config-custom.xml and global.properties file. But SSO is not happning for some reasons. 
So, help me to find out the classes which are using here for authentication.